# DataFrame object is not callable in sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to normalize my data in sql

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/glass/glass.data', 
header=None)
print(data.shape)

class Normalizer():
   [...]


  X, _ = df(return_X_y=True)
  for norm in ['l1', 'l2', 'max']:
      sc1 = Normalizer(norm=norm).fit(X)
      sc2 = skNormalizer(norm=norm).fit(X)
      Xt1 = sc1.transform(X)
      Xt2 = sc2.transform(X)
      print(np.allclose(Xt1, Xt2))'
```

### but I'm getting this error

TypeError          Traceback (most recent call last)
       in ()

```
  ----> 1 X, _ = df(return_X_y=True)
      2 for norm in ['l1', 'l2', 'max']:
      3     sc1 = Normalizer(norm=norm).fit(X)
      4     sc2 = skNormalizer(norm=norm).fit(X)
      5     Xt1 = sc1.transform(X)

  TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is this `X, _ = df(return_X_y=True)` ?

Comment: I can only find `return_X_y` as a parameter to some `sklearn` functions like `load_boston()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this post [here](http://www.example.com/)
You either need a DataFrame.var or numpy.var and the link has some samples that will help you.